# Check whether a point is inside a rectangle by bit operator

Tags: algorithm, geometry, bit-manipulation

Days ago, my teacher told me it was possible to check if a given point is inside a given rectangle using only bit operators. Is it true? If so, how can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might not answer your question but what you are looking for could be this.
[These are the tricks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html) compiled by Sean Eron Anderson and he even put a bounty of $10 for those who can find a single bug. The closest thing I found here is a macro that finds if any integer *X* has a *word* which is [between *M* and *N*](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#HasBetweenInWord)

> **Determine if a word has a byte between m and n**
>
> When m < n, this technique tests if a word x contains an unsigned byte value, such that m < value < n. It uses 7 arithmetic/logical operations when n and m are constant.
>   Note: Bytes that equal n can be reported by likelyhasbetween as false positives, so this should be checked by character if a certain result is needed.
>
> Requirements: x>=0; 0<=m<=127; 0<=n<=128
>
> ```
> #define likelyhasbetween(x,m,n) \
> ((((x)-~0UL/255*(n))&~(x)&((x)&~0UL/255*127)+~0UL/255*(127-(m)))&~0UL/255*128)
> ```
>
> This technique would be suitable for a fast pretest. A variation that takes one more operation (8 total for constant m and n) but provides the exact answer is:
>
> ```
> #define hasbetween(x,m,n) \
> ((~0UL/255*(127+(n))-((x)&~0UL/255*127)&~(x)&((x)&~0UL/255*127)+~0UL/255*(127-(m)))&~0UL/255*128)
> ```

Answer (score 2):

x,y is in the rectangle `{x0<x<x1 and y0<y<y1}` if `{x0<x and x<x1 and y0<y and y<y1}`

If we can simulate < with bit operators, then we're good to go.

What does it mean to say something is < in binary? Consider

```
a: 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1
b: 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1
```

In the above, a>b, because it contains the first 1 whose counterpart in b is 0. We are those seeking the leftmost bit such that `myBit!=otherBit`. (== or `equiv` is a bitwise operator which can be represented with and/or/not)

However we need some way through to propagate information in one bit to many bits. So we ask ourselves this: can we "code" a function using only "bit" operators, which is equivalent to `if(q,k,a,b) = if q[k] then a else b`. The answer is yes:

- We create a bit-word consisting of replicating q[k] onto every bit. There are two ways I can think of to do this:

  - 1) Left-shift by k, then right-shift by wordsize (efficient, but only works if you have shift operators which duplicate the last bit)
  - 2) Inefficient but theoretically correct way:

    - We left-shift q by k bits
    - We take this result and `and` it with 10000...0
    - We right-shift this by 1 bit, and `or` it with the non-right-shifted version. This copies the bit in the first place to the second place. We repeat this process until the entire word is the same as the first bit (e.g. 64 times)
- Calling this result `mask`, our function is `(mask and a) or (!mask and b)`: the result will be `a` if the `k`th bit of `q` is true, other the result will be `b`

Taking the bit-vector c=`a!=b and a==1111..1 and b==0000..0`, we use our `if` function to successively test whether the first bit is 1, then the second bit is 1, etc:

```
a<b := 
  if(c,0, 
    if(a,0, B_LESSTHAN_A, A_LESSTHAN_B), 
    if(c,1, 
      if(a,1, B_LESSTHAN_A, A_LESSTHAN_B), 
      if(c,2, 
        if(a,2, B_LESSTHAN_A, A_LESSTHAN_B), 
        if(c,3, 
          if(a,3, B_LESSTHAN_A, A_LESSTHAN_B), 
          if(...
                  if(c,64, 
                    if(a,64, B_LESSTHAN_A, A_LESSTHAN_B), 
                    A_EQUAL_B)
                  )
             ...)
        )
      )
    )
  )
```

This takes `wordsize` steps. It can however be written in 3 lines by using a recursively-defined function, or a fixed-point combinator if recursion is not allowed.

Then we just turn that into an even larger function: `xMin<x and x<xMax and yMin<y and y<yMax`

Comment: You can probably do this with less code (not necessarily more efficiently) by simply looping through the bits and looking for the first bit set in A not set in B. (how do you determine if a number is less than another number? You look for the most significant different digits. In base 2 there are only two values, so the smaller number will be the first number to have a zero where the other has a one starting from the most significant bit.

Comment: @podperson: I believe this is exactly what I do, in terms of looping. Perhaps I am misunderstanding the point you are trying to convey; what are you suggesting different?

Comment: I meant looping as opposed to writing it out longhand :-) — in essence you've unrolled the loop.

Comment: @podperson: oh, I fear that would be non-functional and therefore not consists of "only bit operators", like the question was asking. However if you mean using `reduce` or `fold-right` functions, that is entirely legitimate, though perhaps obscure. At the very least, I could define a recursive function which would make everything concise. Thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible if the number is a finite positive integer.

Suppose we have a rectangle represented by the `(a1,b1)` and `(a2,b2)`. Given a point `(x,y)`, we only need to evaluate the expression `(a1<x) & (x<a2) & (b1<y) & (y<b2)`. So the problems now is to find the corresponding bit operation for the expression c

Let `ci` be the i-th bit of the number `c` (which can be obtained by masking `ci` and bit shift). We prove that for numbers with at most `n` bit, `c<d` is equivalent to `r_(n-1)`, where

```
r_i = ((ci^di) & ((!ci)&di))  |  (!(ci^di) & r_(i-1))
```

**Prove:** When the `ci` and `di` are different, the left expression might be true (depends on `((!ci)&di)`), otherwise the right expression might be true (depends on `r_(i-1)` which is the comparison of next bit).

The expression `((!ci)&di)` is actually equivalent to the bit comparison `ci < di`. Hence, this recursive relation return true that it compares the bit by bit from left to right until we can decide `c` is smaller than `d`.

Hence there is an *purely bit operation expression* corresponding to the comparison operator, and so it is possible to find a point inside a rectangle with pure bitwise operation.

**Edit**: There is actually no need for condition statement, just expands the `r_(n+1)`, then done.